# How to implement Multi relationship ORM in Kohana?

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-orm

I have problem with relationships in Kohana ORM. I have three models: User, Song and Tag.

```
User {
    has many Songs;
    has many Tags; (followed tags)
}

Song {
    belongs to User;
    has many Tags;
}

Tag {
    has many Users;
    has many Songs;
}
```

Example:

- User 'Naimad' is following tags: Deadmau5 and Inpetto.
- Each tag have two songs:

  1. Deadmau5 tag has: The Veldt and Strobe,
  2. Inpetto tag has: Toca's Miracle and The Storm.

I want to get these songs from tags followed by user, I don't know how to do this. I know that is stupid example, but I tried before I posted this question:

```
$songs = ORM::factory('user', array('name' => 'Naimad'))
    ->tags
    ->songs
    ->find_all();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the **->with('tag')->with('song')**

```
$songs = ORM::factory('user', array('name' => 'Naimad'))
    ->with('tags')
    ->with('songs')
    ->find_all();
```

then to access the value do a loop on the objects  **$s->tags->field_name** ... etc